# Issue with form submission using JavaScript event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with an event listener attached to the **submit** event. Within the event listener, I'm performing some validation and then attempting to submit the form programmatically. However, I'm encountering difficulties in triggering the form submission

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
Pasteform.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  content.value = editor.getValue();

  if(title.value.trim().length === 0){
    title.value = "Not Title";
  }
  if(description.value.trim().length === 0){
    description.value = "Not Description";
  }
  if(content.value.trim().length === 0){
    error.innerHTML = "<p class='text-danger'>Content Can't Be Empty</p>";
  }else{
    Pasteform.submit();
    e.submit();
  }
});
```

In the above code, I'm successfully preventing the default form submission using `e.preventDefault()`. However, when I try to submit the form programmatically using either `Pasteform.submit()` or `e.submit()`, it throws an error saying that submit is not defined.

I have checked that **Pasteform** is referencing the correct form element, and all the other code seems to be functioning as expected.

Am I missing something in my approach? How can I programmatically submit the form within the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `e` is the Event object that was raised. It has no `submit()` method.

You need to call `submit()` on the `form` Element which can be gotten from the `e.target` property:

```
e.target.submit();
```

Also note that your logic seems flawed. Your first two validity checks on `title` and `description` do not affect the form submission. Only the state of the `content` does. You need to re-arrange your logic to check if ***all*** fields are valid. Here's a full example:

```js
Pasteform.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let formValid = true;

  if (title.value.trim().length === 0) {
    title.value = "Not Title";
    formValid = false;
  }
  
  if (description.value.trim().length === 0) {
    description.value = "Not Description";
    formValid = false;
  }
  
  content.value = editor.getValue();
  if (content.value.trim().length === 0) {
    error.innerHTML = "<p class='text-danger'>Content Can't Be Empty</p>";
    formValid = false;
  } 
  
  if (formValid) {
    e.target.submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: title and description are optional so I am just adding default value in them and. Still getting  Uncaught TypeError: e.target.submit is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.

Comment: Apologies - I forgot to add `.target` to the full example! XD

Comment: Bro Still Same! XD

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/Lg83q2sb/. Note that I used `value()` instead of `getValue()` to retrieve the `editor`, as I don't know what WYSIWYG you're using, but that should be irrelevant to the problem. Check your console for errors.

Comment: editor is instance of ace.js problem is this Uncaught TypeError: e.target.submit is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.